# Why is this query slow the first time after I start the service?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

Ok.  Here's what I try to run:

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4;
```

This is one of those "make me a numbers table" queries.

Here's the problem.  If I run this immediately after the SQL Server service is (re)started, it takes forever.  Not forever as in ten seconds and I want it faster.  Forever as in, I let it go over two hours once by accident and still had to kill it.  I'm thinking it just never *ever* comes back.  And ordinarily it takes under two seconds on my machine to run this.

**However**, if I do this instead:

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3;

DROP TABLE Numbers;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4;
```

Then it works as you would expect — the first `SELECT` runs in under two seconds, as does the second.  Why don't I just use the three-table version?  Because there aren't enough entries in `sys.objects` for that number cubed to equal a million result rows.  But that's not even the point anymore.

Anyway, from here on, I can repeat that second `DROP` / `SELECT…INTO` as much as I want, no problem.  Somehow that first three-table version made it ok forever.  At least, till the next time the service is restarted and/or the machine rebooted.  At which point, running that last `SELECT` again never comes back.  Again.

Here's where it starts getting even weirder.  If I pare that first `SELECT` back to a two-table version:

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2;

DROP TABLE Numbers;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4;
```

*This also makes the second `SELECT` run forever.*  As does a one-table version.  Somehow, that three-table version is magical!

**What is going on here?  Why is this slow?**

(And before anyone points out that I'm creating a permanent table in `tempdb`, yes, I know.  Changing to actual temp tables doesn't make any difference.)

---

Added info:

- This is SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition
- Output of `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @find_block_leaders = 1, @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC'` (scripted as XML so it can be read here) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<RESULTS1>
    <RECORD>
        <dd hh:mm:ss.mss>00 00:10:45.066</dd hh:mm:ss.mss>
        <session_id>52</session_id>
        <sql_text>&lt;?query --
SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO Numbers
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4;

--?&gt;</sql_text>
        <login_name>my own login name redacted</login_name>
        <wait_info>(99ms)LCK_M_X</wait_info>
        <CPU>              9,750</CPU>
        <tempdb_allocations>                713</tempdb_allocations>
        <tempdb_current>                702</tempdb_current>
        <blocking_session_id>NULL</blocking_session_id>
        <blocked_session_count>                  0</blocked_session_count>
        <reads>            583,273</reads>
        <writes>                537</writes>
        <physical_reads>                 50</physical_reads>
        <used_memory>                  3</used_memory>
        <status>suspended</status>
        <open_tran_count>                  2</open_tran_count>
        <percent_complete>NULL</percent_complete>
        <host_name>my own machine name redacted</host_name>
        <database_name>tempdb</database_name>
        <program_name>Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query</program_name>
        <start_time>2013-11-23 23:48:19.473</start_time>
        <login_time>2013-11-23 23:47:47.060</login_time>
        <request_id>0</request_id>
        <collection_time>2013-11-23 23:59:04.560</collection_time>
    </RECORD>
</RESULTS1>
```

---

More added info:

Why I'm putting this in tempdb is that it's part of a script intended to be run on virgin installations, and tempdb is guaranteed to be there.  As I said, changing to global temp tables does no different.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? How are you executing this? Manually? In a start up stored procedure?

Comment: This is SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition.  And yes, manually.

Comment: If you use an Itzik Ben Gan [cross joined CTE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/inaccurate-actual-row-counts-in-parallel-plan) approach rather than relying on system tables you will avoid this issue.

Comment: Just out of curiosity to help narrow this down (though I do agree with Aaron that you should put this in either "model" or another permanent DB; I am not sure what you gain having it in "tempdb"): In the working scenario with 2 queries, first one with 3 and second with 4, what happens if you do DBCC FREEPROCCACHE before the second SELECT (the one with 4). Does it still work?

Comment: @srutzky:  Yep, it still works with the DBCC FREEPROCCACHE in there.  Also, added a further note as to why tempdb.

Comment: @Atario, interesting. Thanks for testing. Here are two more things to try. First, add the following to the DBCC command (i.e. run all 4): DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS WITH NO_INFOMSGS; DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE WITH NO_INFOMSGS; DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('ALL') WITH MARK_IN_USE_FOR_REMOVAL, NO_INFOMSGS; Second, have you tried creating the table first? Try this: CREATE TABLE Numbers (Number INT NOT NULL); INSERT INTO Numbers (Number) SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Number] FROM master.sys.all_columns s1 CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns s2

Comment: @srutzky:  Yup, still works with all four DBCC commands in.  If I try it your way, it does finish, but takes significantly longer for some reason -- 678ms + 1304ms = 1982ms total for my three-then-four hack, and 8416ms for your method.  But it does finish!

Comment: Furthermore, I just tried changing mine to use `sys.all_columns` instead of `sys.objects` (only need two tables to get 53e+6-plus results!) and it works all by itself, no need for a primer-run, and in only 1072ms too.  Odd…

Comment: @Atario - You should use the [cross joined CTE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7233/inaccurate-actual-row-counts-in-parallel-plan) approach I already linked above. Or if you must use system objects at least reference ones outside `tempdb`. The `droptemp` internal transaction still deletes rows from `syscolpars` so it is still possible for the user transaction against `sys.all_columns` to take an `S` lock that will conflict with an unfortunately allocated `droptemp`. Though the probability is probably less.

Comment: To see this amend the code in my answer slightly so that connection 1 does `WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id = blocking_session_id) BEGIN EXEC sp_recompile 'P' EXEC P END; SELECT * FROM sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks WHERE session_id = blocking_session_id` and connection two `WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number INTO Numbers FROM sys.all_columns s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns s2 DROP TABLE Numbers END`. When connection 1 stops executing and returns a result you have a hung SPID. Same as the original case.

Answer (score 24):

I <strike>can</strike> could also reproduce this 100% of the time on my machine. (see note at end)

The gist of the problem is that you are taking out `S` locks on system table rows in `tempdb` that can conflict with the locks needed for internal `tempdb` cleanup transactions.

When this clean up work is allocated to the same session that owns the `S` lock an indefinite hang can occur.

To avoid this problem for certain you need to stop referencing the `system` objects inside `tempdb`.

It is possible to create a numbers table without referencing any external tables at all. The following needs to read no base table rows and thus also takes no locks.

```
WITH Ten(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)   
SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO   Numbers
FROM   Ten T10,
       Ten T100,
       Ten T1000,
       Ten T10000,
       Ten T100000,
       Ten T1000000
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

First create a procedure

```
CREATE PROC P
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @T TABLE (X INT)
GO
```

Then restart the SQL Service and in one connection execute

```
WHILE NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                 FROM   sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
                 WHERE  session_id = blocking_session_id)
  BEGIN

      /*This will cause the problematic droptemp transactions*/
      EXEC sp_recompile 'P'

      EXEC P
  END;

SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE  session_id = blocking_session_id
```

Then in another connection run

```
USE tempdb;

SELECT TOP 1000000 IDENTITY(INT, 1, 1) Number
INTO #T
FROM sys.objects s1
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s3
CROSS JOIN sys.objects s4;

DROP TABLE #T
```

The query populating the Numbers table seems to manage to get into a live lock situation with the internal system transactions that clean up temporary objects such as table variables.

I managed to get session id 53 blocked in this manner. It is blocked indefinitely. The output of `sp_WhoIsActive` shows that this spid spends almost all of the time suspended. In consecutive runs the numbers in the `reads` column increases but the values in the other columns remain largely the same.

The wait duration doesn't show an increasing pattern though indicating that it must get unblocked periodically before getting blocked again.

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks
WHERE  session_id = blocking_session_id
```

Returns

```
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| waiting_task_address | session_id | exec_context_id | wait_duration_ms | wait_type |  resource_address  | blocking_task_address | blocking_session_id | blocking_exec_context_id |                                       resource_description                                       |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0x00000002F2C170C8   |         53 |               0 |               86 | LCK_M_X   | 0x00000002F9B13040 | 0x00000002F2C170C8    |                  53 | NULL                     | keylock hobtid=281474978938880 dbid=2 id=lock2f9ac8880 mode=U associatedObjectId=281474978938880 |
+----------------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+--------------------+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using the id in the resource description

```
SELECT o.name
FROM   sys.allocation_units au WITH (NOLOCK)
       INNER JOIN sys.partitions p WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON au.container_id = p.partition_id
       INNER JOIN sys.all_objects o WITH (NOLOCK)
         ON o.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE  allocation_unit_id = 281474978938880
```

Returns

```
+------------+
|    name    |
+------------+
| sysschobjs |
+------------+
```

Running

```
SELECT resource_description,request_status
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks 
WHERE request_session_id = 53 AND request_status <> 'GRANT'
```

Returns

```
+----------------------+----------------+
| resource_description | request_status |
+----------------------+----------------+
| (246708db8c1f)       | CONVERT        |
+----------------------+----------------+
```

Connecting via the DAC and running

```
SELECT id,name
FROM   tempdb.sys.sysschobjs WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE %%LOCKRES%% = '(246708db8c1f)'
```

Returns

```
+-------------+-----------+
|     id      |   name    |
+-------------+-----------+
| -1578606288 | #A1E86130 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Curious about what that is

```
SELECT name,user_type_id
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = -1578606288
```

Returns

```
+------+--------------+
| name | user_type_id |
+------+--------------+
| X    |           56 |
+------+--------------+
```

This is the column name in the table variable used by the stored proc.

Running

```
SELECT request_mode,
       request_status,
       request_session_id,
       request_owner_id,
       lock_owner_address,
       t.transaction_id,
       t.name,
       t.transaction_begin_time
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks l
       JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions t
         ON l.request_owner_id = t.transaction_id
WHERE  resource_description = '(246708db8c1f)'
```

Returns

```
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| request_mode | request_status | request_session_id | request_owner_id | lock_owner_address | transaction_id |    name     | transaction_begin_time  |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| U            | GRANT          |                 53 |           227647 | 0x00000002F1EF6800 |         227647 | droptemp    | 2013-11-24 18:36:28.267 |
| S            | GRANT          |                 53 |           191790 | 0x00000002F9B16380 |         191790 | SELECT INTO | 2013-11-24 18:21:30.083 |
| X            | CONVERT        |                 53 |           227647 | 0x00000002F9B12FC0 |         227647 | droptemp    | 2013-11-24 18:36:28.267 |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

So the `SELECT INTO` transaction is holding an `S` lock on the row in `tempdb.sys.sysschobjs` pertaining to the table variable `#A1E86130`. The `droptemp` transaction cannot get an `X` lock on this row because of this conflicting `S` lock.

Running this query repeatedly reveals that the `transaction_id` for the `droptemp` transaction repeatedly changes.

I speculate that SQL Server must allocate these internal transactions on user spids and prioritise them before doing the user work. So the session id 53 is stuck in a constant cycle where it starts up a `droptemp` transaction, is blocked by the user transaction running on the same spid. Rolls back the internal transaction then repeats the process indefinitely.

This is borne out by tracing the various locking and transaction events in SQL Server Profiler after the spid becomes hung.

[image: Profiler]

I also traced the locking events prior to that.

#### Lock Events Blocking

[image: LockAquisitionPatternBlockingTransaction]

Most of the shared key locks taken out by the `SELECT INTO` transaction on keys in `sysschobjs` get released immediately. The exception is the first lock on `(246708db8c1f)`.

This makes some sense as the plan shows nested loops scans of `[sys].[sysschobjs].[clst] [o]` and because temporary objects get given negative objectids they will be the first rows encountered in scan order.

I also encountered the situation described in the OP where running a three way cross join first seems to allow the four way one to succeed.

The first few events in the trace for the `SELECT INTO` transaction there are an entirely different pattern.

[image: LockAquisitionPatternNonBlockingTransaction]

This was after a service restart so the lock resource values in the text data column are not directly comparable.

Instead of retaining the lock on the first key and then a pattern of acquiring and releasing subsequent keys it seems to acquire a lot more locks without releasing them initially.

I presume there must be some variance in execution strategy that avoids the issue.

---

Update

[The Connect Item I raised about this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809544/internal-droptemp-transaction-can-cause-unkillable-spid) has not been marked as fixed but I am now on SQL Server 2012 SP2 and can now only reproduce temporary self blocking rather than permanent. I still get the self blocking but after some amount of failed attempts  to execute the `droptemp` transaction successfully  it appears to go back to processing the user transaction. After that commits the system transaction then is executed successfully. Still on the same spid. (eight attempts in one example run. I'm not sure if this will be consistently repeated)

Comment: Interesting, all around the table variable. Wonder if it's related in any way to [this deadlock](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/11/t-sql-queries/single-tx-deadlock) or the 4 linked Connect items.

Comment: A couple of points that still haven't been resolved. (1) Why does it happen with 4 cross joins but not 3 as described in the OP. (2) How does it allocate these internal transactions to particular spids. In the meantime [I've posted a connect item report here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809544/internal-droptemp-transaction-can-cause-unkillable-spid)

Comment: That's some hardcore sleuthing, my friend.

Comment: And the inserting lots of rows into a table in `tempdb` seems to be a prerequisite too. Moreover I tried increasing the size of the initial `tempdb` data file (was at 8MB + 10% growth) and now no longer see the issue. So wonder if it only occurs if the transaction gets hung up waiting on an autogrow.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than chase this problem, why don't you just create the table once in the `model` database, then it will be created for you in `tempdb` automatically?

For the actual problem, we don't know. My first guess would be that your initial size for your tempdb file(s) is very small (like, 1MB). So, when you create the table, it has to expand the file(s) to accommodate it. This can be quite expensive *especially* if you don't have [instant file initialization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2009/12/23/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization.aspx) enabled, and it can also be very expensive to grow the log to accommodate the activity required there as well.

Other than that, we could keep guessing, but *you* will be better suited to investigate what is actually happening. Questions you'll want to ask:

1. For the spid that is trying to create the table, what does `sys.dm_exec_requests` say for `wait_type`?
2. Does it have a `blocking_session_id`?
3. If so, what is *that* session doing?

Comment: Ah, question undeleted.  That's better.  To answer your questions:  (1) it oscillates between NULL and LCK_M_X; (2) it oscillates between 0 and the value of session_id (in sync with (1)); and (3) danged if I know.

Comment: Oh, forgot about the first suggestions.  Adding it to model won't do any good, since this is part of a large script intended to be run on virgin installations to create and populate a whole database from scratch.

Comment: @Atario - RE: "danged if I know". Install [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/files/folders/beta/entry42453.aspx) and run `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @find_block_leaders = 1, @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC'` whilst it is blocked. Let us know what you find.

Comment: It just lists the blocked query itself (blocking_session_id is NULL, blocked_session_count = 0).  Does it help to know this is a local installation and I'm the only one accessing it?

Comment: @Atario Simply connecting via management studio will run queries in the background and there may be other sources of queries too (SQL Server agent, Reporting Services, Startup procedures). Next time you reproduce this please try the steps in my answer.

Comment: @MartinSmith:  I followed your steps and found the same kind of thing (different ID/session/etc. numbers of course) except for the one where you see the X column name (I didn't do the procedure part at the top).  Instead, I see these value pairs:  account_name/256, type/231, privilege/231, mapped_login_name/256, permission_path/256

Comment: @Atario - So that is columns `account_name sysname, type nvarchar, privilege nvarchar, mapped_login_name sysname, permission_path sysname` Looks like the particular stored procedure that table variable belongs to is `msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_has_server_access` so I presume SQL Server Agent fires it off. Though any concurrent stored procedure execution that uses cached temporary objects might cause this.