# Is it possible to create a contant table without using table variable or temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table A which needs to join table B.

table B is a constant which 2 columns

```
year, flag
----------
2010, A1
2011, A2
2012, A3
2013, A4
2014, A5
```

is it possible to do something like below (* invalid syntax in sql server, just use it to show what I mean):

```
SELECT *
FROM A RIGHT JOIN (
   2010, 'A1';
   2011, 'A2';
   2012, 'A3';
   2013, 'A4';
   2014, 'A5';
)
B ON A.year = B.year
```

I do not want to use table variable or temp table for B. Is there other choices?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a real table? And why would you not want to use a table variable or temp table?

Comment: It is because this is part of a Stored Procedure. we need to join this query again to some other queries. If there is something like this exists in sql server, then we can write 1 query, let sql optimize it. If use table variable, seems slow down it.

Comment: CTE (Comman Table Expression) is your friend :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use [`VALUES`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to create a table of literal values in the plan

```
SELECT *
FROM   A
       RIGHT JOIN ( VALUES(2010, 'A1'),
                          (2011, 'A2'),
                          (2012, 'A3'),
                          (2013, 'A4'),
                          (2014, 'A5') ) B(year, flag)
         ON A.year = B.year
```

This table is not indexed however and is limited to a max 1000 rows.

Comment: +1 for the new information didnt know this.but is there any particular situation where you have to do it ???

Comment: This will work but you are better off having this in a real table in the database, so that in 2015 you can add a value and all the places this is used will automatically include it. That way you don't have to look for all the refences in your code. That is one of teh purposes of storing information in tables.

Comment: @MuhammedAli - It is just syntactic sugar for a derived table with `UNION ALL`. These virtual tables are [useful for generating a numbers table from scratch](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7233/3690) without querying system objects for example. Cross joining real tables takes locks which [may have undesirable results](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20155337/73226)

Comment: lol `syntactic sugar` and cheers pal for the interesting read :)

Comment: A nice answer! Maybe you can create it as a view and reuse it as wish.